# Android Studio 2.2.3 - Samsung skins not compatible?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-virtual-device

I just patched android studio from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3 this morning.  During the process, I was informed that the AVD skins I downloaded from Samsung (Galaxy S7, etc.) were no longer compatible and gave me only one option - deleting them.

I see nothing in the 2.2.3 bugs fixed list that would account for this.  Does anyone have any idea how I can continue to use those skins?